# Web API controller to get details of a travel plan or a leave request

Tags: c#, json, api, generics, controller

My web API has 3 controllers for get, post and users CRUD. I named it as `DetailsControllor`, `FormControllor` and `AuthControllor`. In the details controllor, I used a `switch case` to find out which type of details needed, but I found that code is repeated in switch case. Can I use generics to minimize code or is there any other way to carry out these things?

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("details/{id}")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetDetails(string id)
    {


        try
        {
            var content = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse();
            switch (id)
            {
                case "leave":
                    RequestBase LeaveInput = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<RequestBase>(content);
                    Task<LeaveForm> LeaveOutput = repo.GetLeaveRequest(LeaveInput);
                    response.Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(object), LeaveOutput, jsonFormatter);                       
                    break;

                case "travel":
                    RequestBase travelInput = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<RequestBase>(content);
                    Task<BaseTravel> travelOutput = repo.GetTravel(travelInput);
                    response.Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(object), travelOutput, jsonFormatter);
                    break;


            }
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

             HttpResponseMessage responseToClient = Request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode)422);
             responseToClient.Content = new StringContent(e.message, Encoding.Unicode);
         throw new HttpResponseException(responseToClient);  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! This is great for a first post, it's nice to have you here and I hope you get some fine answers.

Answer (score 2):

I'd re-think your `switch`:

- `RequestBase LeaveInput = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<RequestBase>(content);` is repeated, the only difference it is assigned to a different variable depending on the case.
- `response.Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(object), travelOutput, jsonFormatter);` is also repeated, with the only difference being the second parameter.

In fact, the three lines of each case are virtually identical, except for `repo.GetLeaveRequest()` and `repo.GetTravel()`, which suggests to me that the switch should happen at a lower level.

Perhaps you could do something like this:

```
private ObjectContent GetObjectContent(string id, string content)
{
    var input = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<RequestBase>(content);

    object output;
    switch (id)
    {
        case "leave":           
            output = repo.GetLeaveRequest(LeaveInput);
            break;

        case "travel":
            output = repo.GetTravel(travelInput);
            break;
    }

    return new ObjectContent(typeof(object), output, jsonFormatter);
}
```

Thus the contents of your try could become:

```
var content = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var response = Request.CreateResponse();
response.Content = GetObjectContent(content);
return response;
```

Note that I'm not sure this works, consider it more like an idea than workable code. (I just don't feel like starting up VS to test this.)

---

Just a couple of quick remarks:

- Local variables like `LeaveInput` and `LeaveOutput` should be camelCase.
- You explicitly use `RequestBase` and `HttpResponseMessage` and `Task<LeaveForm>`: why not use `var` like elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. I will try this one and let you know If it works!